# Is it possible to change the blink rate of cursor using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, cursor

I have text input. I want to change the blink rate of the cursor. Is it possible to do that using jQuery.

```
<textarea id="some">

</teaxtarea>

<script>
$(function(){
   $('#some').focus();
});
</script>
```

i.e. after I focus on the textarea, will it be possible to change the blink rate of the cursor?

Please comment if the question is not clear.